# Laravel User Authentication Scaffolding -> Saving data into two tables

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I am relatively new to laravel and have a project that requires a bit of manual configuration.

Background:

- Working with Authentication Scaffolding (handles the user
  registration and login)
- I have two tables: Profile and Users.
- All Users have one Profile.
- But not all Profiles have a user.

Setup:
**Profile table** => id, name, avatar, etc.
**User Table** => profile_id, email, password

Since the Laravel Auth (Scaffold) handles the Registration and Login. I am trying to save data into the Profile table before saving the user table.

```
protected function create(array $data)
{

    $profile = Profile::create
    ([
        'slug' => $data['name'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
    ]);

    $user = User::create
    ([
        'profile_id' => $profile->id,
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);

    return $user;
}
```

But this is not working. And the error message is telling me there is no profile_id assigned in the query.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

How are your models set up? If Eloquent and your DB is set up correctly you can do this:

```
$profile = new Profile;
$profile->slug = $data['name'];
$profile->name = $data['name'];

$profile->save();
// At this point now you'll be able to get an ID of the profile

$user = new User;
$user->profile_id = $profile->id;
$user->name = $data['name'];
$user->email = $data['email'];
$user->password = bcrypt($data['password']);

$user->save();

return $user;
```

Comment: Yes that was my original idea but I am getting the following: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'profile_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (John, john@gmail.com, $2y$10$NoMoLSL1Sgek4enF2k2x7eL2Yo.To8O5uiriCrZdZk9rlW4CVbK1u, 2017-08-02 18:08:17, 2017-08-02 18:08:17))

Comment: Check your database migration, you need to make sure your profile id column is set to **auto increment**